# Flutter initState not being called

Tags: flutter

When I open a chat page as a pop up the `initState` gets called the first time, but when I use `Navigator.pop(context)` and then open the chat page again the `initState` does not get called and I get an error for my `StreamSubscription` -> `The method 'cancel' was called on null.` But I do initialize it in the `initState`.

Why isn't the `initState` being called THE SECOND time I open the chat page, WHEN THE FIRST TIME I OPEN IT IT WORKS PERFECTLY?

```
  // ignore: cancel_subscriptions
  StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (this.chat != null) if (widget.chat.messages.isEmpty)
      this._prevMessages().then((value) {
        this._initMessages();  // <-- WHERE I'M INITIALIZING THE StreamBuilder
        this._scrollToBtm();
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    this._streamSubscription.cancel(); // <-- THE ERROR
    this._scrollController.dispose();
    this._msgTEC.dispose();
    this._msgFN.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  _initMessages() {
    Funcs.log('Init Live Messages...');
    this._streamSubscription = APIs().chats.messagesLive(...);
  }
```

The exact log:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'cancel' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: cancel()
```

Comment: `_streamSubscription` is null - you need `this._streamSubscription?.cancel()`

Comment: The question is why is it null the second time? But not the first??

Comment: `_streamSubscription` is not assigned anywhere in your code - how anyone could tell you what you do with `_streamSubscription` withot seeing your code?

Comment: It is being assigned inside the `this._initMessages();` method. Like I said in the question when I first open the chat page it works just fine, but when I close it and then open it again that's when it acts like it's not being called.

Comment: most likely `this.chat` is `null` or  `widget.chat.messages.isEmpty` is `false` - try to add some `print` statements

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you initialize **_streamSubscription** before invoking it asynchronosuly. There must be some default value set. What's happening is that where you are calling **_initMessages()**, it is being invoked inside a **Future**,which means it is invoked after (or not, it could be at anytime) initialization completes.

You can either make sure to **await** **this._prevMessages()**, thus:

```
  @override
  void initState() async {
    if (this.chat != null) if (widget.chat.messages.isEmpty)
      await this._prevMessages().then((value) {
        this._initMessages();  // <-- WHERE I'M INITIALIZING THE StreamBuilder
        this._scrollToBtm();
      });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Or you can initialize the **_streamSubscription** object before running the initialization code. There must be some default value set here.
Also the dispose method should not be invoked before initialization. This means that you have code somewhere that is disposing the object the moment that the item gets initialized.

Comment: Yaa I don't think you can put async in the initState... But Like I said in the issue this only happens the second time I open the chat page. NOT THE FIRST. The first time I open it it works just fine. when I close it and then open the chat page again then it acts weird.